# Create Slack thread using only WebhookClient in Python

Tags: python-3.x, slack-api

I am implementing an optimization script in Python that executes several threads in parallel. Each thread posts a message to a Slack channel informing it started, and they post status updates to the same channel as they progress. The problem is that parallel threads are not deterministic in the order they progress, so status reports get messy for being posted to the same Slack channel.

I am using `slack_sdk.WebhookClient` to post the message to an URL like this one: `'https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXX/YYYYYY/abababababababa'`.

I would like every thread of the execution to open a Slack chat thread so all the messages from that execution thread would be clustered together in one slack chat thread and wouldn't mix with messages from other execution threads.

Is there any way to open Slack chat threads using `WebhookClient` without needing to use a user credential authorization?

Answer (score 0):

To post the status updates as threads, you need the time stamp of the parent post.

 Add the argument `ts` to your request and it will add it to the thread of parent post.

**Check here:**

 1.https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks#threads

 **2. https://api.slack.com/messaging/sending#threading**

Comment: This requires user authorization, I said in my question that I want to do it without it